# I am getting http code as 000 or Time out on server for the cURL in shell script

Tags: shell, curl, amazon-ec2

When i am executing this script on server i am getting response code as 000 but i am getting status code as 200 when i am executing this on local machine. This is happening for the same URL & Script.

```
flag=0
for URL in $@
do
        STATUS=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' $URL)
        if ([ $STATUS -gt 400 ] || [ $STATUS -lt 100 ]); then
               echo $URL "is not working fine, STATUS CODE is "$STATUS
flag=1
        else
               echo $URL "is  working, STATUS CODE is "$STATUS
        fi
done

if [ $flag -eq 1 ]; then
exit 1
fi
```

I have seen in some forums that the problem is due to SSL. Please let me know what can be changed in above script.

Comment: `$(...)` denotes command substitution; you're capturing the __output__ of the `curl` command into the variable `STATUS` which doesn't seem to do what you intend to.

Comment: I am passing the URLs on command line along with the execution of file. `sh url_check.sh http:\\www.google.com` which is giving result on local machine but is not giving on server for **one** of the URLs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

also use `-k` or the `--insecure` parameter with your curl commandline to overcome this issue.

Comment: Can you please explain, What it will do ?

Comment: The `-k` or `--insecure` is necessary to validate the response without 'securing' the connection with proper SSL/TLS authentication between your server and the remote server (commonly necessary in test environments that do not have real certs).

From curl.haxx.se:

(TLS) By default, every SSL connection curl makes is verified to be secure. This option allows curl to proceed and operate even for server connections otherwise considered insecure.

The server connection is verified by making sure the server's certificate contains the right name and verifies successfully using the cert store.

Comment: However, as hinted at, using the -k parameter effectively nullifies the actual reason for using https, namely that the server identity is authenticated by means of its certificates. So using the -k option opens you up to the data being downloaded from the server being from an untrusted party.